# Why can't you HTTP PATCH without any params?

Tags: node.js, rest, http, express

I'm using MongoDB, Express.js and Node.js to make a REST API for an Eccomerce project. In my user model, I have cart array which allows me to keep track of items in the user's cart. I save several fields of information on the cart such as itemId, quantity, etc. So I don't want to pass these in as params in the route as PATCH /users/cart/:id/:quantity/:etc , instead I would like to send them as JSON body. All my routes have middleware "authenticate" that checks the header for an auth token, and sets the user on req.user, this way I don't need to include the user's id in as a param in the route. Is this an appropriate design approach? My PATCH route fails when I make the route without a param at the end (/users/cart), which leads me to assume a param is required. Looking at docs, this seems to be the case. This feel redundant since I have middleware. Is there an alternative approach that gets the job done? This is what my code looks like now, I don't user req.params.id, its just there to make the code work.. Thanks in advance!

```
 app.patch('/users/cart/:id', authenticate, (req, res) => {

  var body = _.pick(req.body, ['itemId','units', 'quantity', 'name', 'ppg', 'ppe', 'ppi']);
  console.log(body);


  User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id}, {$push: {cart: body}}, {new: true})
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).send();
      }
      res.send({user});
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
      res.status(400).send();
    });
});
```

Comment: If you don't want to use the `id` in the http route, just remove it from the route definition: `app.patch('/users/cart', /* ... */)`.

Comment: That's what I'd like to do, but it doesn't work. Nothing happens, I get the object back as the response, but the changes aren't made. Also, its worth noting that if I toss in a console.log('testing') in the route WITHOUT the id, nothing gets logged...

Comment: Well my quick test simply does not include the `id` in the route and I just send a payload, and it's working just fine. I generally include a logger for the requests themselves ( at least in development ) so I would suggest that your `PATCH` request is probably malformed. You should probably be testing with `curl` as the most raw form of issuing a request. i.e `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PATCH -d '{"name":"xyz"}' http://localhost:3000/users/cart`, but you also likely need to include cookie information or whatever the middleware is using to match the session data.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for the suggestion! I always use Postman. After more troubleshooting I've narrowed the problem to the route name. If i change the route from `/users/cart` to just `/cart` it works. I have a `DELETE` and `GET` route at `/users/cart/:id`. Maybe this somehow interferes with having a `PATCH` route on `/users/cart` ?